# How to raise IndexError in two iterable objects when iterating over them with zip()

Tags: python, arrays, oop, iterator

For learning purposes I have tried to implement a class that does some of the basic functionality of a numpy array in standard Python. However, it does not behave correctly if I use an operation (add, subtract, multiply, truedivision) with two objects of the array type. In that case, it alternates between returning the correct result and returning an empty object of the arr type.

```
class arr:

    def __init__(self, vals):
        self.vals = vals
        self.idx = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'arr({self.vals})'

    def __add__(self, new_value):
        if type(new_value) in [int, float]:
            return arr([val + new_value for val in self.vals])
        if type(new_value)==arr:
            return arr([val + new_val for val, new_val in zip(self.vals, new_value)])

    def __sub__(self, new_value):
        if type(new_value) in [int, float]:
            return arr([val - new_value for val in self.vals])
        if type(new_value)==arr:
            return arr([val - new_val for val, new_val in zip(self.vals, new_value)])

    def __mul__(self, new_value):
        if type(new_value) in [int, float]:
            return arr([val * new_value for val in self.vals])
        if type(new_value)==arr:
            return arr([val * new_val for val, new_val in zip(self.vals, new_value)])

    def __truediv__(self, new_value):
        if type(new_value) in [int, float]:
            return arr([val / new_value for val in self.vals])
        if type(new_value)==arr:
            return arr([val / new_val for val, new_val in zip(self.vals, new_value)])

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.idx += 1
        try:
            return self.vals[self.idx - 1]
        except IndexError:
            self.idx = 0
            raise StopIteration

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.vals)
```

I could trace this back to the fact, that when I e.g. add two such arrays, the idx variable of the second array does not get set back to 0 for each second time I use such an operation. I suspect the list comprehension with the zip() function only raises the StopIteration error for the first of the two arrays and stops before it can raise it for the second array? How can this be implemented correctly?

Comment: Change `__iter__` to `return iter(self.vals)`? You could also reset `self.idx` to `0` *inside* `__iter__`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, `__iter__` gets called every time a new iteration starts? Anyways, your second solution works for me, the first one however did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at how to correctly implement an iterator in python: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator, it seems that you need to also initialize the index in the `__iter__()` method.